# lerna initialization error when running npx init command

Tags: npm, lerna, npx

I get the following error when I try to do lerna project initialization. I followed the instructions on the lerna [docs](https://github.com/lerna/lerna#getting-started) readme.md and still not able to get it to work. I tried searching for this error and cant seem to find any useful leads to solving this.

Can someone help me with resolving this:

```
lerna notice cli v3.20.2
lerna info Initializing Git repository
lerna ERR! Error: spawn git ENOENT
lerna ERR!     at notFoundError (C:\Users\[userid]\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\lerna\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:6:26)
lerna ERR!     at verifyENOENT (C:\Users\[userid]\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\lerna\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:40:16)
lerna ERR!     at ChildProcess.cp.emit (C:\Users\[userid]\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\lerna\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:27:25)
lerna ERR! lerna spawn git ENOENT
```

I have tried:
running the commands

```
npx lerna init
lerna init
```

I tried these on

```
empty folder (except .git)
empty folder (without .git)
mkdir folder while running the command
```

None of those worked for me.

Can someone help me resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem. I thought I would post an answer for anyone who is running into the same issue.

I was using `windows cmd` to do `> git init` on an empty folder and then doing `> lerna init`, the `> git init` was not initializing a git repo on the empty folder although it doesnt throw an error or complain.

I switched to using `git cmd` to `> git init` and then `> lerna init` worked whether I ran it from `windows cmd` or `node cmd` or `git cmd`